# Oath problem with Microsoft personal account authentication

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Hello guys i have this problem when i try to autenticate a personal account microsoft through Oauth2.
My endpoint URL is configured on common already
[image]

The application is configured as a multitenant:
[image]

My manifest is:

```
{​​​​​​
"id": "0982f18d-116c-45c0-b1ee-59dd9fa3344b",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "002543f2-87b6-43e4-91a3-cfdef655dc7a",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-02-04T10:09:11Z",
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {​​​​​​
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
}​​​​​​,
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "AppBotTipBook",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {​​​​​​
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
}​​​​​​,
"passwordCredentials": [
    {​​​​​​
        "customKeyIdentifier": null,
        "endDate": "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z",
        "keyId": "86c3141b-02ac-4d47-9ecf-0cabb8ba2fc4",
        "startDate": "2021-02-04T10:10:43.464Z",
        "value": null,
        "createdOn": "2021-02-04T10:10:44.3986206Z",
        "hint": "_3D",
        "displayName": "botlogin"
    }​​​​​​
],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "unisalerno.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {​​​​​​
        "url": "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect",
        "type": "Web"
    }​​​​​​
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {​​​​​​
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {​​​​​​
                "id": "570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca",
                "type": "Scope"
            }​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​
                "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                "type": "Scope"
            }​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​
                "id": "b340eb25-3456-403f-be2f-af7a0d370277",
                "type": "Scope"
            }​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​
                "id": "e383f46e-2787-4529-855e-0e479a3ffac0",
                "type": "Scope"
            }​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​
                "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                "type": "Scope"
            }​​​​​​,
            {​​​​​​
                "id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                "type": "Scope"
            }​​​​​​
        ]
    }​​​​​​
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
```

}​​​​​​

But when i try to login with an account hotmail i get this error:
AADSTS50020: User account 'xxxxxxxxx@hotmail.it' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Università di Salerno' and cannot access the application '002543f2-87b6-43e4-91a3-cfdef655dc7a'(AppBotTipBook) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

How i should solve this problem? Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

The setting that you mentioned seems correct. I will show you my steps to sign in with an external user.

**1. Create an invited user**

[image]

**2. Register an application**

[image]

Same `Supported account types`:

[image]

Same `signInAudience` like yours:

[image]

**3. Add a client secret:**

[image]

**4. Test the application with [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)**

① Request an authorization code in browser, and login with the external user account.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://myapp
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

② Request an access token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={}
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&code={code from previous step}
&redirect_uri=https://myapp
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret={}
```

[image]